# How to insert to mysql from asp.net using vb?

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net

I am trying to insert into a mysql table. Here is my code...

```
        Dim cmdText = "INSERT INTO complete_log ('cust_id', 'business', 'note', 'date_stamp') values (@cid,@bus,@notey,@datey)"
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection("server=theipofserver;user id=id;password=mypass;database=thedatabase")
    Using cmd = New MySqlCommand(cmdText, conn)
        conn.Open()
        Dim testy As String
        testy = TextBox1.Text
        Dim dater = Date.Today + TimeOfDay
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", c_id)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bus", c_business)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@notey", testy)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datey", dater)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
```

But, I get the following error:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''cust_id', 'business', 'note', 'date_stamp') values ('ID','null','first one'' at line 1
```

the table I am trying to insert into has 4 columns that are all varchars with plenty of space (varchar(100))

Here are more details on the error... error occurs on line 31...

```
Line 29:             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@notey", testy)
Line 30:             cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datey", dater)
Line 31:             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Line 32:         End Using
Line 33:         TextBox1.Font.Bold = True
```

So, what am I doing wrong here? Any tips on better ways to insert into mysql tables would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do not forget to close the connection (better enclose in using statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use quotes around table or column names.

```
INSERT INTO complete_log (`cust_id`, `business`, `note`, `date_stamp`)
values (@cid,@bus,@notey,@datey)
```

If you want to escape table and column names then use backticks. But you only need to escape [reserved words in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).

Comment: Well, I feel silly now... Thanks a lot juergen! I'll mark this as the answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Do not specify column names in apostrophies

Instead of

```
Dim cmdText = "INSERT INTO complete_log ('cust_id', 'business', 'note', 'date_stamp') values (@cid,@bus,@notey,@datey)"
```

Do

```
Dim cmdText = "INSERT INTO complete_log (cust_id, business, note, date_stamp) values (@cid,@bus,@notey,@datey)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
INSERT INTO complete_log ('cust_id', 'business', 'note', 'date_stamp')
```

to

```
INSERT INTO complete_log (cust_id, business, note, date_stamp)
```